# How to know which servlet and JSP version am I using?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Can you tell me how to know which servlet and JSP **version** am I using ? 
I use **NetBeans IDE** 7.1.2 for creating Servlets and JSP.

Comment: That should be specified in your web.xml file.

Comment: The IDE doesn't have anything to do with the JSP and Servlet version of your application. That's declared in the web.xml.

Comment: Check the declarations in your xml files. Also, if you can, check the jars in the classpath of your project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: @acdcjunior the jars are not the best reference here, since a web application server could handle more than one version of servlets thus accepting wars that use old servlet versions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Are you sure? I thought the servlet spec didnt allow that. Anyway, the jars would tell more what is the version the Netbeans project is targeting.

Comment: @acdcjunior the jars will vary depending on the web application server target (that's why you choose it when creating the project).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree, that's why I thought they could help (if he had chosen servlet 2.5 while creating the project, the corresponding jars should be at the project's classpath). The "are you sure" part was about the server handling more than one version of the servlet-api.

Comment: As an additional information, in case you are using Tomcat: [The mapping between the Servlet/JSP specifications and the respective Apache Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get the details programatically using [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) `#getMajorVersion()` and `#getMinorVersion()`.

For knowing the JSP version corresponding to the Servlet, you can get details from this [Tomcat page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Tomcat+Versions).

Below is a brief summary (check Tomcat's corresponding version at the link above):

- Servlet 4.0 uses JSP 2.3
- Servlet 3.1 uses JSP 2.3
- Servlet 2.5 uses JSP 2.1
- Servlet 2.4 uses JSP 2.0
- Servlet 2.3 uses JSP 1.2
- Servlet 2.2 uses JSP 1.1
- Servlet 2.1 uses JSP 1.0

Comment: This only returns the max version as **supported** by the servletcontainer. This doesn't return the version currently **used** by the running webapp. This is dictated by `web.xml`.

Answer (score 40):

You can easily check the JSP,SERVER and SERVLET version. Add the following code in your jsp page after that run using any IDE Tools.

```
Server Version: <%= application.getServerInfo() %><br>
Servlet Version: <%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %>
JSP Version: <%= JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %> <br>
```

Answer (score 22):

The version is declared in the `web.xml` file using the attribute `version`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
...
</web-app>
```

[Read more](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml)

Comment: in `web.xml`, this version in starting tag `<web-app version="3.1">` tells us about servlet version? In my case it's 3.1?

Comment: The web.xml file is not necessary.